# Logged into multiple Gmail accounts; first is automatically chosen for oAuth

Tags: google-account, google-multi-login, oauth

I am logged into multiple accounts on Gmail. I had a bad habit for a number of years where I'd switch email addresses and forward all my mail from the previous one.

The problem is, when I try and log into a different site through Google oAuth, then the first Gmail account I logged into automatically gets selected.

Let me explain with an example. On Stack Overflow I have accounts for email1 and email2. Only the email1 account is used and it is linked to a Gmail account which I don't actually use anymore. If I logged into email2 first, then I will not get the option to select the correct account for Stack Overflow. I need to log out of all accounts in Gmail which is tedious.

Comment: Why not add email2 to your Stack Overflow account? Then you could remove email1 and the problem will be solved.

Comment: @ale thanks that did the trick here. However a lot of websites don't let you change the email you log in with when it's with a third party.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is not offering you the Google multi login option so you can choose the account to use, the solution is to use separate browsers or, for those browsers that support it, a different browser profile.

I have one Google account I use for several "professional" Stack Exchange sites, and another I use for sites about some of my hobbies. I want to keep the two separate, so I have separate profiles in Chrome: one for "normal/professional" stuff, one for hobbies.